# Attempting to get a table from SQL Request

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm working on a project right now and I need to do some request to my DB via SQL *PLUS.

Here is what I'm trying to do.
I want to get a table in which I get Professor first and last name with those conditons (I have to verify the first condition, and then the other):

- (First) In a session (let's say 12004), a prof did teach those two courses, **INF3180** and **INF2110**
- (Second) In another session, 32003, a prof did teach those two courses, **INF1130** and **INF1110**

Here is the code that created the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE Professor
(professorCode  CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 lastName           VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 firstName      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PrimaryKeyProfessor PRIMARY KEY     (professorCode)
)
;

CREATE TABLE Group
(sigle      CHAR(7)     NOT NULL,
 noGroup    INTEGER     NOT NULL,
 sessionCode INTEGER        NOT NULL,
 maxInscriptions    INTEGER     NOT NULL,
 professorCode  CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PrimaryKeyGroup PRIMARY KEY   
(sigle,noGroupe,sessionCode),
CONSTRAINT CESigleGroupeRefCours FOREIGN KEY    (sigle) REFERENCES Cours,
CONSTRAINT CECodeSessionRefSession FOREIGN KEY  (sessionCode) REFERENCES 
Session,
CONSTRAINT CEcodeProfRefProfessor FOREIGN KEY(professorCode) REFERENCES 
Professor
) 
;
```

And here is my current not working request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Professor.firstName, Professor.lastName
FROM            Professor, Group
WHERE           Group.professorCode = Professor.professorCode
                AND Group.sessionCode = 32003
                AND (Group.sigle = 'INF1130' AND
                     Group.sigle = 'INF1110')
                OR Group.sessionCode = 12004 
                AND (Group.sigle = 'INF3180' AND
                     Group.sigle = 'INF2110')
```

I know there is a way to combine both results, but I can't seem to find it.

**There is only one match possible in that case** :

- Only one match with 32003 : INF1130, INF1110
- None match with 12004 : INF3180, INF2110

The resulting table is supposed to look like this :

```
--------------------------
First Name       Last Name
--------------------------
Denis            Tremblay
```

The proposed solution given by **Gordon Linoff** looks very good, except it returns me no table since with the following the code, it needs to have the 4 courses and 2 sessionCode to be included. The issue here is that it needs to verify both condition and append the result. Let's say the conditions for the session 12004 results to nothing, then I can consider it as NULL. Then, the second condition, with the session 32003, gives me one match. It should append both results to give me the table presented over.

I want to do one request only for this.

Thanks A LOT!

**EDIT** : Reformulated

**EDIT2** : Gave an example of a known match

**EDIT3** : Further explanation why the proposed solution isn't working

Comment: Not sure of Oracle or sql plus but you are likely looking for where in or where exists.  As one record cannot satisfy both sigle conditions.

Comment: Please provide examples of professors who match and do not match the conditions.

Comment: Only one professor matches with the request. It respond only for INF1110, INF1130 and 32003. No one matches INF3180, INF2110 and 12004. It has to show the one that match

Comment: Just added an example! @GordonLinoff

Comment: Example output isn't helpful without matching sample input - including data which should *not* appear in the result set. You said your query is 'not working', but what does that mean - are you getting an error? Too many results? Not enough? Please include the current result in your question, along with the sample data, and explain why it is wrong.

Comment: @AlexPoole done! Thanks a lot for the insight!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I included further explanation in the post directly, under the resulting table

Comment: So... you want any professor who taught *both* courses in *either* session, not necessarily all four? i.e. (INF1130 and INF1110 in 32003) OR (INF3180 and INF2110 in 12004) ? With OR rather then AND between those two conditions? Will you always be looking for two `sigle` values per `sessionCode` or will this vary?

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried to modify the code given by GordonLinoff, but without success. I attempted to sepate the (g.sessionCode, g.sigle) IN ( (32003, 'INF1130'), (32003, 'INF1110'), (12004, 'INF3180'), (12004, 'INF2110')) into (g.sessionCode, g.sigle) IN ( (32003, 'INF1130'), (32003, 'INF1110')) OR (g.sessionCode, g.sigle) IN ( (12004, 'INF3180'), (12004, 'INF2110')). Except, it didn't worked. And yes, two sigil per sessionCode max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to list any professor who *either* taught INF1130 and INF1110 in 32003; or taught INF3180 and INF2110 in 12004. Unfortunately you've presented that as AND (i.e. they have to have taught all four courses - one pair of courses AND the other), not OR (one set of courses OR the other).

As a long-winded way of expanding what I think you want:

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName
FROM Professor p
WHERE (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupX g
    WHERE professorCode = p.professorCode
    AND sessionCode = 32003
    AND sigle = 'INF1130'
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupX g
    WHERE professorCode = p.professorCode
    AND sessionCode = 32003
    AND sigle = 'INF1110'
  )
)
OR (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupX g
    WHERE professorCode = p.professorCode
    AND sessionCode = 12004
    AND sigle = 'INF3180'
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupX g
    WHERE professorCode = p.professorCode
    AND sessionCode = 12004
    AND sigle = 'INF2110'
  )
);
```

Four subqueries isn't going to be terribly efficient. You could do mutiple joins instead.

If you will always be looking for two `sigle` values per `sessionCode` then you could modify Gordon's answer to count how many matches each `sigle`, by adding that to the group-by clause:

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName
FROM GroupX g
JOIN Professor p
ON p.professorCode = g.professorCode
WHERE (g.sessionCode, g.sigle) IN ( (32003, 'INF1130'), (32003, 'INF1110'),
                                    (12004, 'INF3180'), (12004, 'INF2110')
                                  )
GROUP BY p.firstName, p.lastName, g.sessionCode
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you did have a professor who taught all four then you would get them listed twice; if that can happen you could add your `DISTINCT` back in, though that feels a bit wrong. You could also use a subquery and `IN` to avoid that:

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName
FROM Professor p
WHERE ProfessorCode IN (
  SELECT professorCode
  FROM GroupX
  WHERE (sessionCode, sigle) IN ( (32003, 'INF1130'), (32003, 'INF1110'),
                                  (12004, 'INF3180'), (12004, 'INF2110')
                                )
  GROUP BY professorCode, sessionCode
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

(I've changed `Group` to `GroupX` because that isn't a valid identifier; because it's a keyword. I assume you've changed your real names - maybe from another language?)

Comment: worked perfectly fine. I know know what I did wrong. Thanks a lot to all that helped me!

Comment: Yea, from french

Answer (score 1):

Think:  `group by` and `having`.  More importantly, think `JOIN`, `JOIN`, `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName
FROM Professor p JOIN
     Group g
     ON g.professorCode = p.professorCode
WHERE (g.sessionCode, g.sigle) IN ( (32003, 'INF1130'), (32003, 'INF1110'),
                                    (12004, 'INF3180'), (12004, 'INF2110')
                                  )
GROUP BY p.firstName, p.lastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.sigl) = 4;  -- has all four
```

Comment: Here is the translated question :
We search for the codes and names of the teachers, without repetition, which were taught at once
INF3180 and INF2110, during the session whose code is 12004. Also, the code and names
teachers, who have taught courses INF1130 or INF1110, during the session
the code is 32003

Comment: @GuillaumeLevesque . . . The four conditions are that the professor taught all four classes.  That is what this query does.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my main language. The table I have to return is either teachers that taught INF1130 and INF1110 in 32003 AND teachers that taught INF3180 and INF2110 in 12004. My bad, I can't express myself correctly :/

Answer (score 0):

use modern join

```
SELECT Professor.firstName, Professor.lastName
FROM            Professor join "Group" g on
            g.professorCode = Professor.professorCode
               where  g.sessionCode in( 32003,12004 )
                AND g.sigle in( 'INF1130', 'INF1110','INF3180','INF2110')                        
             group by  Professor.firstName, Professor.lastName
             having count( distinct sigle )=4
```